Clark Transform code
I come through the following link dealing with clark Transfrom
:https://github.com/rubinsteina13/C_SPACE_VECTOR_TRANSFS_LIB/blob/master/vector_transfs.c
But there is something I missed in the program when the Clark Transform is calculated
 void tFFClarke_abc2albe(tFFClarke* ptFFClarke){
    ptFFClarke->fAl = (2.0f/3.0f)*ptFFClarke->fA - 
              (1.0f/3.0f)*(ptFFClarke->fB - ptFFClarke->fC);
    ptFFClarke->fBe = (2.0f/SQRT_3)*(ptFFClarke->fB - ptFFClarke->fC);
}

Please, could someone explain to me why the last line is multiplied by  (2.0f/SQRT_3) ? rather then (SQRT_3/3) ? Because I understood from the first line that we took a positive sequence with the fact that the original clark Transform is multiplied by 2/3 is it is discribed in
https://www.mathworks.com/help/mcb/ref/clarketransform.html
Thanks in advance
